# Find the Empty excel file when upload to datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

User upload the inputs through the Excel file.
I want to find that excel file is empty or else.I check the content length and file size for find empty file..size is vary between empty files(without type and user type data and delete the all data to make an empty)For example content length for emptyfile 8714 but user type any data and delete all the data then the content length is 8104 like that

So I convert the excel file to datatable and check the datatable is null or not.when convert empty file to datatable the datatable have the default column F1.so datatable =null not work.Pls help me

My code:

```
string dirpath = Server.MapPath("~") + "uploadfile\\";
                string LocalFilePath = dirpath + fileName;
                fileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(LocalFilePath);

                string fileType = Path.GetExtension(fileName);        
                string SourceConstr = string.Empty;
                var Inputs = ProjectAttributeMasterService.GetInputAttributes(7);

                if (fileType == ".xls" || fileType == ".xlsx")
                {



                    if (fileType == ".xls")
                    {
                        SourceConstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + LocalFilePath + "';;Extended Properties= 'Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";

                    }


                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(SourceConstr);
                    con.ResetState();
                    con.Open();

                    System.Data.DataTable dtl = new DataTable();
                    System.Data.DataTable dts = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", con);
                    da.Fill(dtl);


                    if ((dtl.Rows.Count >= 1 || dtl.Columns.Count >= 1) && !dtl.Columns.Contains("F1")){
            }
          else
          {
         /empty file
          }
```

dtl.Columns.Contains("F1")..If i use this condition even the Excel contain Data in cell "F1" then return Empty..and F1 is not default column for all server...So Its also not fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code as follows:

```
     OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", con);
     da.Fill(ds);
    if ((ds.Table.Count >= 1)
     {    
          if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
          {
             //Excel contains data
          }
          else
          {
             //file is empty
          }   
     }
     else
     {
       //file is empty
     }
```

Comment: Datatable does not contain the  Table method..got error in (dtl.Table )

Comment: Hi  Priya i edit the code and used dataset instead datatable try using this way..

Comment: or just checking datatable for rows greater than 0 will work like 
if (dtl.Rows.Count > 0){data exist}
else{not exist}