# How to know if the excel file is empty or not in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have upload website where i am able to block all files which are of 0 bytes.
There i have checked the file size using the property ContentLength. If content length is 0 then it shouldnot upload. This isn't the case of excel cause it has some contentlength. Hence iam unable to block an excel file even though the content is empty.

Comment: read the `excel` check `row count` of all `sheets`

Comment: Isnt there any other methods apart from checking each row in excel.

Comment: I would prefer reading the Excel with the epplus lib (available on nuget) but here is a sample with ole(db) https://stackoverflow.com/q/13411547/169714

Answer (score 1):

An empty excel file has a content length > 0 because even an empty excel file has a file size > 0 which is caused be the file format of office files.

When creating a blank excel file you can simply rename the *.xlsx file to *.zip and have a look at all files of which an excel file consists.

Due to this there isn't any other way of checking whether an excel file has content than checking the rows one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check Worksheet.UsedRange, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange.aspx. I'd experiment with Worksheet.UsedRange.Count. Note that it may be 1 in two cases: 1) A1 cell is empty and 2) A! cell isn't empty, so you'll need to check this, too. Also, depending on what you call a "blank sheet", you may need to check if Worksheet.Comments and Worksheet.Shapes are empty. Sorry, no code.

ref: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b9cdfbd7-5ae9-41f7-b7e8-ebc00e835d45/how-to-check-if-excel-sheet-is-blank-using-excel-interop-c-or-vb-code-please?forum=exceldev#546316e8-8745-42e8-9c0d-063d1373dfbe